# Angular RxJS Observable loading error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6

I have declared an observable variable

```
workOrders: Observable<IWorkOrders[]>;
```

And then i load that observable this way.

```
  this.bs.getWorkOrders()
  .pipe(map(data:IWorkOrders[]) => this.workOrders = data)),
    .subscribe((data: IWorkOrders[]) =>
      // this.workOrders = data;
      this.woSubject.next(data),
  );
```

but when i do it i see a red squiggly under the this.workOrders = data line. And also when I hover it says
[ts] Type 'IWorkOrders[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workOrders=this.bs.getWorkOrders();` will work

`workOrders` is of type `Observable`. `data` is of type `IWorkOrders[]` 
Since those are 2 different types, thus error you are getting. You cannot assign `IWorkOrders[] to Observable`.

Comment: @Sumchans 2 different types - thus error - iv edited answer.

Comment: so you saying if i declare this way workOrders:IWorkOrders, i can call it like this from my component this.bs.getWorkOrders().subscribe.

Comment: Yep you can if you rly need `Obeservable` in your component insteed of emited value.

Comment: Okay thanks, still new to angular & observables, totally confusing concepts.

Comment: Observable is littlebit like plain old listener pattern + streams

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states - `workOrders` is of type `Observable<IWorkOrders[]>`, while the `data` variable is of type `IWorkOrders[]`. In your case you are trying to assign two incompatible types to one another. In the `map` function you are receiving the value of the `Observable` which is of type `IWorkOrders[]`.

What you have to do, is to declare `workOrders` as an `IWorkOrders[]` instead of an `Observable` of that type:

```
workOrders: IWorkOrders[];
```

P.S. you have an extra trailing comma `.pipe(map(data:IWorkOrders[]) => this.workOrders = data)), <--`

Comment: I tried that it worked that way, then how do i subscribe to the workOrders variable from another component if it is not an observable.

Comment: There are many different ways to pass data to other components, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be an observable for me to subscribe from other components

Comment: Please explain what you want to do because it's not clear by looking at just 3 lines of code with no context.